# Using modulus in one time pad?

Tags: symmetric, algorithm-design, one-time-pad

I would like to know what is the real purpose of using a modulus in the equivalent of a Vernam cipher:

Data $d$, large number $M$.
Assume the key length is $\lambda$ bits. Then $M$ could be $2^\lambda$.
$k$ is picked from $\{0,1\}^\lambda$ using a pseudo random function (PRF)

Encryption: $C = k + d \pmod{M}$
Decryption: $d = C - k \pmod{M}$

What's the purpose of using $M$?

Comment: 1) What would you use instead? It's correct and it's convenient. What more do you want? 2) Nowadays we typically use xor (addition modulo 2) which is fast in software and encryption/decryption are the same function. 3) why do you claim M is a large number? It's often 2 or 256 and very rarely larger than 64 bits or so.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you think of as an alternative.

If you think of the scheme where you do not use $M$ as a modulus, but the keys a picked as:
$$
k \leftarrow \{1, \ldots, M-1\} 
$$
Encryption: 
$$
C = d + k
$$
Decryption:
$$
d = C - k
$$
Then the scheme is insecure. One way to see this is to note that we have $C \geq d$. So the ciphertext communicates the information that $d \leq C$.

You could also think of a scheme where there is no $M$ at all:
$$
k \leftarrow \mathbb{Z} 
$$
Encryption: 
$$
C = d + k
$$
Decryption:
$$
d = C - k
$$
This would be secure, however, it would be impossible to implement because there is no way to sample $\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers) uniformly at random (think about it, how would you do that?).

So you see $M$ is really quite essential to the scheme.

Comment: So, for security reason, we must use the modulus ???

Comment: You could say that, yes.

Comment: @zof In addition to this answer, maybe [**this page**](https://sites.google.com/site/dtcsinformation/encryption/modulo-encryption) about “modulo encryption” can help you grasp it completely. (That “modulo encryption” also represents a nice string to throw at search engines btw.)

Comment: Yes, but in terms of security, what is the role of M !?

Comment: @zof: it is there in order to make the +/- an operation over a finite group; OTP needs to be performed over a finite group (or, at least, a finite latin square) in order to be secure.

Comment: so, we have to use a finite group to provide security !? Can you please give me any link...for this !?

Comment: My group theory is a little rusty, but I think you can do with any finite cyclic group. It needs to be a cyclic because this ensures that for any two elements $d$ and $C$ in the group there is a unique element $k$ so that $C = d + k$. This means that if you see $C$ then it could be an encryption of any message $d$. The group must be finite because otherwise there is no way to sample it randomly.

Comment: @GuutBoy: actually, the group doesn't need to be cyclic; given $d$ and $C$, that there is a unique $k$ s.t. $C=d+k$ is a property of all groups, cyclic or not.  As for why the group needs to be finite, well, for groups of size $\aleph_0$, you can't select a random element equiprobably, and for groups of size $\aleph_1$ and larger, well, you run into issues that you can't express almost all the members within a finite number of bits.

Comment: So, for generating the keys, I use a PRF such as HMAC, which outputs a key of fixed size .e.g. 160 bits so, if the key generation is secure, what is the need of using a MODULUS ???
Where are you, experts !!

Comment: @poncho: that sounds right.

Comment: @zof: I am not sure how to explain it any further. The scheme just doesn't make sense with out the modulus.

Comment: @GuutBoy: Yes, Thanks, but your response is related to key generation, I modified my question, the keys are generated using a PRF ! Now, what is the role of the modulus M ???